# JBoss EAP and MSSQL driver doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, jboss, persistence, jboss-eap-7

I installed the mssql driver by this [example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Example_Microsoft_SQLServer_Datasource1.html) on my JBoss EAP 7. Startup will throw the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4098)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
>   at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:322)

Comment: Which version of the driver do you use?

Comment: 6.1.5 from here https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From version 6 the modul.xml has to be extended by `<module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>`

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```